# Button.setOnClickListener doesn't work at all

Tags: java, android

I am programming a metronome for Android and use a thread for playing the sound in the rythm the user says but somehow my `setOnClickListener` won't work. The button doesn't even click when clicked. What is wrong with my code?

```
    startb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_but);
    stopb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_but);

    startb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            running = true;
            bpm_val = findViewById(R.id.metr_input);
            value = bpm_val.getText().toString();
            int beat = Integer.parseInt(value);

            Soundplay(beat / 60);       //The beats per second

        }

    });

    stopb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            running = false;
        }

    });
}

public void Soundplay(final long bps) {
        startb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_but);
        stopb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_but);
        running = true;
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();

                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.metronome_klack);

                int i = 0;
                while (running) {
                    if(i == 1000) {
                        mp.start();
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    try {
                        sleep(bps);
                        i++;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: SO is a terrible debugger. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized the button twice in your code.
First in **onCreate()** method and second time in **Soundplay(final long bps)** method. You can remove the initialization from **Soundplay** method. As it seems that button is initialized on its click listner itself. I think that's the issue.

```
public void Soundplay(final long bps) {
    //Remove this portion
    **startb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_but);**
    **stopb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_but);**

    ...
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: findViewById does not initialize new button it's just find the view with respective id.

Comment: I now see that none of my buttons in the whole application work. I extend all my activities from a navigation Drawer Activity and inflate all activities instead of setContentView. Could this be the problem?